# How to run regular JavaScript in React/Preact application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am trying to use masonry in a Preact app, tried [several React plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react%20masonry&ranking=popularity) using react/compat but they are all failing.

This is how I'm trying:

```
const App = () => (
  <Landing name="shoecare">
    <!-- all the working code -->

    <!-- here -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.2.2/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var grid = document.querySelector(".how__list");
    new Masonry(grid, {
      itemSelector: ".how__item",
      columnWidth: document.querySelctor('body').clientWidth / 2 - 16,
    });
    </script>
    <!-- end -->
  </Landing>
);

clab(<App />);
```

But it fails to compile:
[image]

Is it posible?

I managed to run some regular JS onclick, like so;

```
<span class="services__nav-previous" onClick={(e) => scrollLeft()}>
```

Comment: You might find this useful. You use a `ref` to get a handle on the DOM element rendered by react, then you can run `useEffect` to setup the non-react component: https://rossbulat.medium.com/react-using-refs-with-the-useref-hook-884ed25b5c29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you're using functional components, so to have any js code inside of them you should do it like this

```
const App = () => {
  // your js code here
  return (
  // here you put your components
  )
}
```

EDIT: and you don't put < script >< /script > inside of your functional component, you add them in your index.html file, not in app.js

Comment: The problem that i'm facing is that i have no experience in Preact (i didn't develop this app), but if I try what you suggest the highlighter crashes: https://i.imgur.com/FMYjRco.png any thoughts?

Comment: check you brackets, after const App =() => should go { } not ()

Comment: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html you could try the tutorial to understand how it works tho

Comment: Sorry, you are right. but problem persists https://i.imgur.com/VDyvucj.png And i wish i had time for that.. as i mentioned i'm already very late in this one..

Comment: change return brackets to () not {}, my fault

Comment: and you dont use name while trying to show to className, there's a collision between name in namespaces, so change name for class names to className